# Vim highlights closed folds

Tags: folding, highlight

Vim has this odd behaviour: when I launch it in a terminal emulator under X,
it highlights closed folds, but when I launch it in console, closed folds'
representation is more sensible: they are just light blue, not in 
standout/reverse mode. I would very much like Vim to behave under X the same
as in console, as I find highlighted folds highly distracting.

Which option controls this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `:hi Folded`.  You probably have

```
Folded         xxx term=standout         . . .
```

Importantly, vim's `term=` entry denotes a terminal it thinks cannot produce color (as opposed to `cterm=`).  So, one potential way to resolve your issue is to properly set up color in xterm and vim.

Alternatively use

```
hi! Folded term=NONE
```

However, if your color scheme overrides this, you will need to do this each time your colors are applied.